# Как избежать повтора кода при работе с датами? (LocalDate)

Tags: java, дата, методы, localdate, повторы

Реализую метод, который отражает каждый год от заданной даты до текущей.
Формат требуемого вывода:

```
0 - 31.12.1990 - Mon

1 - 31.12.1991 - Tue
```

и далее до 2021 года.
Код получился такой

````
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1990, 12, 31);
    String formattedDate = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT));
    String str = "0 - " + formattedDate + " - " + date.getDayOfWeek();
    LocalDate date1 = date.plusYears(1);
    String formattedDate1 = date1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT));
    String str2 = "1 - " + formattedDate1 + " - " + date1.getDayOfWeek();
    System.out.println(str + System.lineSeparator() + str2);```
````

вывод:

0 - 31.12.1990 - MONDAY

1 - 31.12.1991 - TUESDAY

Как оптимизировать лучше? слишком много повтора кода и вручную приходится создавать каждую дату, прибавляя год к предыдущей.

Comment: Завернуть все в цикл. Именно для таких вещей они и существуют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коротко  примерно так:

```
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1990, 12, 31);
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

        for(int i = 0; i<= Period.between(date,now).getYears()+1;i++){

            LocalDate temp = date.plusYears(i);
            String str = i + " - " + temp.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)) + " - " + temp.getDayOfWeek();
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Смысл думаю понятен